# Was Janet responsible for inviting the demon into her house?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring-2

In the movie *The Conjuring 2* we saw Janet playing with a Ouija Board and then leave the board under the bed. So was that the cause of the demonic possession in her house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the movie is [based on the "real life events": yes](http://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/conjuring-2-enfield-poltergeist/).

> **Did the paranormal activity begin after they played with a Ouija
>   board?**
>
> Yes, at least according to the real Janet Hodgson, who says that she
>   and her sister Margaret played with a Ouija board just prior to the
>   start of the supernatural activity. *-Daily Mail Online*